# Prioritization based on three factors

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, algorithms, biostatistics, genetic-algorithms

**Background:** Sales reps visit doctor and detail about a product/drug. One visit is termed as one call. In return he writes the prescriptions to doctors prescribing that particular drug.

**Problem Statement:** There are three variables to be considered based on which an algorithm needs to be developed which will help prioritize the doctors.

1. **Potential Untapped:** Prescriptions written by the doctor about products which are analogs/competitive to the client's product.
2. **Potential Tapped:** Prescriptions written by the doctor about the client product.
3. **Call Value:** It is the ratio of total calls given to a doctor to the total prescriptions he has written. E.g.: A doctor who was given 10 calls, and who in turn wrote 10 prescriptions is less important than a doctor who was given 5 calls, and who in turn wrote 10 prescriptions...

The aim is to use these 3 variable and come up with an algorithm that will help to prioritize the doctors available.